# Attempting to Pipe Child Processes

Tags: python

For my Operating Systems course we're attempting to use piping to get two children to randomly pick two values and add them for a Sum, I've got an idea and an approximation of what the code should be but I keep getting local variable errors and lack of child process errors. Our class is using a version of Linux in VirtualBox to run our Python code in the Terminal.

```
import os, sys
import random

r0, w0 = os.pipe()
r1, w1 = os.pipe()

def child0():

        pid = os.getpid()

        random.seed(pid)
        v = random.randrange(101)
        v1 = str(v)
        os.write(w0, v1.encode("utf-8"))

def child1():

        pid1 = os.getpid()

        random.seed(pid1)
        v = random.randrange(101)
        v2 = str(v)
        os.write(w1, v2.encode("utf-8"))

def main():
        paid = os.getppid()

        if os.fork() !=0:
                print("[",paid, "]: spawning children")
                if os.fork() !=0:
                        #Still In Parent
                        print("Still In Parent")
                else:
                        cid = os.getpid()
                        x = child0()
                        v1 = os.read(r0, 10)

                        child0()
                        print("[",cid, "]: picks", int(v1))


        else:
                print("[",paid, "]: reaping")
                cid1 = os.getpid()
                z = child1()
                v2 = os.read(r1, 20)

                child1()
                print("[",cid1, "]: picks", int(v2))

                print("[",paid, "]: Sum is", int(v1) + int(v2))

main()
```

Comment: Please post edit your question and post your errors.

Comment: I... Think @Konafets means that you have some typos. For example, your import statements need to be unindented.

Comment: Good point, but actually I meant he should put the errors he mention in his post.

Comment: This would be considerably wieldier code if you wrote it with `subprocess.Popen()`, with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` as appropriate.

Comment: I've seen some usage of subprocess before but our professor hasn't really told us how to use it. My knowledge is really basic based on the python I've learned. Also this is the first time I've asked a question the import are indented cause I was unfamiliar with posting code samples.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that what the OP is saying is that he's _purposefully_ not using `subprocess` because he's trying to learn about how the OS handles forks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... It looks like your code is mixing child process and parent process bits.

On line 28, you fork. You check to see if you're in the child or the parent process. That's good. But then on line 42, you act as if you're in the child process when you're clearly in the parent process. It's a similar situation on line 30.

Here's a better definition for `main`:

```
def main():
  paid = os.getppid()
  if os.fork() !=0:
    print("[",paid, "]: spawning children")
    if os.fork() !=0:
      #Still In Parent
      print("Still In Parent")
      print("[",paid,"]: reaping")
      v1,v2 = os.read(r0,10),os.read(r1,10)
      print "Child 0 picks",int(v1)
      print "Child 1 picks",int(v2)
      print "sum is: ",int(v1)+int(v2)
    else:  #Now in child 0...
      cid = os.getpid()
      child0()
  else:      #Now in child 1...
    cid1 = os.getpid()
    child1()
```

This other code here doesn't quite work for me, but it describes... kind of... What you'd do.

```
import os,random,time

def print_as(le_pid,message):
  print("[",le_pid,"]: ",message)


def main():
  r0,w0 = os.pipe()
  r1,w1 = os.pipe()
  if os.fork() != 0:#In main
    if os.fork() != 0: #Still in main
      pid_main = os.getpid()
      print_as(pid_main,"I'm the parent, successfully isolated.")
      time.sleep(10)  #This is here so that the children can spawn and choose.
      print_as(pid_main,"Children spawned, reaping values...")
      v0,v1 = os.read(r0,10),os.read(r1,10)
      print_as(pid_main,"Received values.")
      print_as(pid_main,"Output is: "+str(int(v0)+int(v1)))
    else: #In child 0
      pid_0 = os.getpid()
      print_as(pid_0,"Child 0 successfully spawned.")
      random.seed(pid_0)
      v = random.randrange(101)
      v0 = str(v)
      print_as(pid_0,"I'm picking: "+v0)
      os.write(w0,v0.encode("utf-8"))
  else:#In child 1
    pid_1 = os.getpid()
    print_as(pid_1,"Child 1 successfully spawned.")
    random.seed(pid_1)
    v = random.randrange(101)
    v1 = str(v)
    print_as(pid_1,"I'm picking: "+v1)
    os.write(w1,v1.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: How would I call the Child's PID when printing what the child picks.

Comment: I've posted some more code that describes that. It looks like there's some issues with the pipes, though, so you'll have to decipher that. I'm no expert in this, and I dislike using python 3.

Comment: That's fair, The original code works fine, the issue I'm having is my Professor wanted the output to be the [PID] Picks X for the child prints. Unfortunately the second code looks totally out of my depth i get an Idea of what it's trying to do, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: print_as is essentially just printing out that header of [PID]: and then functioning as a standard print function. I've moved the child1 and child0 functions into each `else` clause for conciseness. Other than that, it's the same. There's an error, though, and I don't know where it is.

Comment: Ah, crud monkeys. I figured out what was wonky with my code. I switched the read and write ends of the pipes. It's fixed, now, and it works perfectly.